# Constructing a tree from a list of edges: missing Leaf nodes

Tags: haskell, ghci

I wrote the below code to construct a tree with given vertex given a list of connections between vertices.

```
type Connection = (Int,Int)
data Tree = Leaf Int | Node Int [Tree] deriving (Eq,Read,Show)

makeTree :: Int -> [Connection] -> Tree
makeTree x [] = Leaf x
makeTree indx connections =  Node indx otherTrees where
  otherTrees = [makeTree i cx | i <- directConnections, let cx = removeConnectionsTo indx connections]
  directConnections = map (\(x,y) -> if (x == indx) then y else x) $ filter (\(x,y) -> x == indx || y   == indx) connections

removeConnectionsTo :: Int -> [Connection] -> [Connection]
removeConnectionsTo indx = filter (\(x,y) ->    x /= indx && y /= indx)
```

For some reason, the inputs below give me surprisingly different results:

`makeTree 1 [(1,2),(1,3)]` gives me `Node 1 [Leaf 2,Leaf 3]`

`makeTree 1 [(1,2),(1,5),(2,3),(2,4),(5,6),(5,7)]` gives me `Node 1 [Node 2 [Node 3 [],Node 4 []],Node 5 [Node 6 [],Node 7 []]]`

I am running GHCi, version 7.4.1 on OS X 10.8.2.

I don't understand why I get Leaf twice in the first example (correct) but node with empty subtree lists in the second example (incorrect).

Comment: What results were you expecting?

Comment: The second answer should have contained "Leaf 3" instead of "Node 3 []" etc.

Comment: I'm downvoting this question because the title is unhelpful and the content reads a bit like "please fix my code" without any clear evidence of investigation etc.

Comment: @BenMillwood : Improved title and question now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick fix would be to just check if `otherTrees` is empty before deciding whether to build a `Leaf` or a `Node`, e.g.

```
makeTree indx connections
  | null otherTrees = Leaf indx
  | otherwise       = Node indx otherTrees
  where ...
```

To understand what is happening here, let's add a little instrumentation:

```
import Debug.Trace

makeTree :: Int -> [Connection] -> Tree
makeTree ix cs | traceShow (ix, cs) False = undefined
makeTree x [] = ... -- leave rest of the function as before
```

Now load it up into GHCi, and let's see what the recursive calls are:

```
> import Control.DeepSeq
> (show $ makeTree 1 [(1,2),(1,5),(2,3),(2,4),(5,6),(5,7)]) `deepseq` ()
(1,[(1,2),(1,5),(2,3),(2,4),(5,6),(5,7)])
(2,[(2,3),(2,4),(5,6),(5,7)])
(3,[(5,6),(5,7)])
(4,[(5,6),(5,7)])
(5,[(2,3),(2,4),(5,6),(5,7)])
(6,[(2,3),(2,4)])
(7,[(2,3),(2,4)])
()
```

As you can see, the list in the second argument is not empty which is why it doesn't match the first case of your function, so you'll either need to add some additional checks as in my example, or make sure that you filter out the rest of the connections.

Comment: Your solution worked, but I still can't figure out why mine did not. When invoking a function, the function declarations are selected in order of declaration, so the `makeTree x [] = Leaf x` should have matched first, isn't it?

Comment: It doesn't match, because the list in the second argument isn't empty. The only connections that get removed from the list on the path down to a node are the ones that mention its ancestors, so e.g. when you get to `makeTree 7`, `connections` still has `[(2, 3), (2, 4)]` in it.

Comment: Arrgh, took me awhile to figure out! Thanks for your info about DeepSeq and trace - they will come in handy :)